# who should implement unit testcase?

Tags: testing

1. The person who implements a feature
2. The person who work with 1.person (partner or pair)
3. The interns or freshman in the team
4. QA
5. The person who design or make the feature

I want to listen other office's work process.

Comment: I interned at a company and did 85% of the unit tests for a pretty large project. It seems that most people typically feel the person who writes the code (and therefor knows its expected outcome) should be the one testing the code, but, as I've seen first-hand, this varies in reality.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure this question is a good fit for StackOverflow.

But my opinion is that the person who implements the feature should also implement the test case, ideally before implementing the feature... in order to achieve a test-driven development type workflow.

Comment: Anyone can - eg getting QA to encapsulate a bug precisely is very helpful. But TDD ftw :-)

Comment: @doctorlove Agreed, in fact ANY unit test is better than none at all.  But some QA are not well-versed in coding and getting them to write unit tests can be difficult.

Comment: True, mind you some people who write features can't write unit tests for toffee